# Error: Could not find or load main class using external libraries

Tags: java, linux, macos, terminal

I am trying to execute a java program I wrote. Doing the compiling is no problem ( I used : `javac -cp \* *.java`). But when i try to run it (using: `java -cp \* FirstTestCase 1 1 data`), it says `Error: Could not find or load main class FirstTestCase`.

this is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Timer;

public class FirstTestCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, CertificateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int amount = 100000;
        int threads = 150;
        String file = "newData";
        if(args.length == 3)
        {
            amount = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            threads = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            file = args[2];
        }
        X509Downloader d = new X509Downloader(amount, threads, file);
        d.getCertificates();
    }

}
```

We are also using external libraries, 4 to be precise. We use the `-cp \*` to include them all. When i run `java FirstTestCase 1 1 data` it succeeds to run it but then throws Exception about it not finding the classes that we use from the external libraries.

I normally use an IDE and therefore i barely have any experience using the terminal to start java programs.

I do use a Mac at the moment to test it, but we will run this program later on a server using Linux (in case the operating system matters)

Comment: Is `FirstTestClass` in a package?

Comment: Nope, no package is used. I looked on Google and saw that others had that problem as well, but in my case it is not